# Continuous Status 504

Tags: stellar-core, stellar-sdk, javascript-sdk, nodes

I have been developing a Multi-sig based project and keeps on getting the 504 status so many times when making transaction. I have checked out the testnet staus of Horizon network as well and it seems to be little under stress but network is up and running still I cant get my transactions complete.

I am hereby attaching part of the response I get back when signing a transaction

```
data: {
      type: 'https://stellar.org/horizon-errors/timeout',
      title: 'Timeout',
      status: 504,
      detail: 'Your request timed out before completing.  Please try your request again. If you are submitting a transaction make sure you are sending exactly the same 
transaction (with the same sequence number).'
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. It is related to surge pricing mode when the network is too busy with too many transactions to process.

IIRC, Horizon API waits 30 seconds for the tx to be processed, and after 30 seconds, It returns 504 Timeout.

So add more fee to the tx to have higher priority in the network, or retry until it succeeds.

I resolved this to retry logic.

Answer (score 0):

May be this would help.

let MultiSecretID = ["SecretId1","SecretId2","SecretId3",....]
let transaction = new StellarSdk.Transaction(base64XDREnvelope, StellarSdk.Networks.TESTNET);
let newSign = [];
await MultiSecretID.map((sign, i) => {
newSign .push(StellarSdk.Keypair.fromSecret(sign));
});
transaction.sign(...newSign);